# Complex polynomial injective on the unit disk?

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove or disprove,
for all real $\alpha$ and natural $n\geq 2$

$f(z)=z^{n}+ne^{i\alpha } \cdot z$ is injective on the unit disk.

I'm not sure how to approach this,  I've seen other 2 problems showing a function is one-to-one on the disk, by reaching a contradiction with integrals and approximations, but they usually provide a useful inequality on the derivative. Not sure if it's even a relevant remark, or whether the claim true or false

Comment: Just a note, there was a misspelling to the function and the 2nd term is now multiplied by z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative is given by$$f'(z)=n(z^{n-1}+e^{i\alpha}).$$Now let $z_0,z_1$, be two distinct points in the unit disk. We have$$f(z_1)-f(z_0)=\int_\gamma f'(z)dz=n\int_\gamma(z^{n-1}+e^{i\alpha})dz=n\int_0^1(\gamma(t)^{n-1}+e^{i\alpha})\gamma'(t)dt,$$where $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ is a parametrization of the straight segment connecting $z_0$ and $z_1$. Note that there is a half plane containing the values inside the integral for all $t\in[0,1]$, and hence, the integral cannot vanish. It follows that $f$ is indeed one to one on the unit disk.

Comment: I don't get it- Why can we say that this integral cannot vanish? What do you mean with "a half plane containing the values inside the integral"? I hope someone takes a look at this question ...

Comment: @Thesinus In the case at hand, the half plane is the set $\{z|\mathrm{Re}(e^{-i\alpha}z)>0\}$. Everything under the integral sign is contained in this half plane, which is a *convex* subset of the complex plane. Hence, the integral lies in this half plane too.